# How can I add my Tomcat Application in onelogin for SAML?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, onelogin

I am having a Web Application running on tomcat and hosted on amazon, I want to add it as an **SAML** Service Provider which allows single sign on(**SSO**) in onelogin(https://www.onelogin.com/)

I have a free trial account in one login, and In **Add App** section I can see many applications like salesforce,aws and all but how can I add my own application there ?
I clicked on Suggest an App and and gave my application URL. Is there anyway I can add my own application as an SP in onelogin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [SAML Test Connector](https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us/articles/202673944-How-to-Use-the-OneLogin-SAML-Test-Connector). It works with any generic SAML Service Provider.

If you also need to add SAML support to your tomcat application, you should know that Tomcat does not have a SAML SP provider implementation itself, so you will need to add SAML support to the java application. For that you can use:

- [OIOSAML](https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml/tree/v2.0.0/)
- [spring security](https://svn.softwareborsen.dk/oiosaml.java/sp/trunk/docs/intro.html)
- [java-saml](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/)
- [shibboleth](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPJavaInstall) (It requires also Apache).

Comment: I have added it as SAML Test Connector. But I am getting some error . Something to do with my configuration I feel. I have explained my configurations [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150754/how-to-configure-my-web-application-as-saml-test-connector-sp-using-onelogin) Any help ?

Comment: When I click on the SAML 2.0 Endpoint (HTTP) I am getting a 500 error.