# How to configure My Web Application as SAML Test Connector (SP) using Onelogin?

Tags: saml-2.0, onelogin

I have added my web application into onelogin using [SAML Test Connector](https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us/articles/202673944-How-to-Use-the-OneLogin-SAML-Test-Connector).
In Configuration tab I have given the following values

> Recipient : http://localhost:8080/em/live/pages/samlAuth/
>
> ACS(Consumer) URL Validator* : ^
>
> ACS (Consumer) URL* :http://localhost:8080/ws_em/rest/accounts/consume-saml
>
> Login URL : http://localhost:8080/ws_em/rest/accounts/produce-saml

Where http://localhost:8080/ws_em/rest/accounts/produce-saml creates an SAML Request by taking IssuerUrl, SAML EndPoint Copied From Onelogin SSO Tab and ACS url as http://localhost:8080/ws_em/rest/accounts/consume-saml.

```
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/produce-saml")
    public com.virima.em.core.Response SAMLAuthentication(){
         com.Response resp = new com.Response();
         AppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings();
         appSettings.setAssertionConsumerServiceUrl(ACSUrl);
         appSettings.setIssuer(IssuerUrl));
         AccountSettings accSettings = new AccountSettings();
         accSettings.setIdpSsoTargetUrl(IdpSsoTargetUrl);
         AuthRequest authReq = new AuthRequest(appSettings,accSettings);
         Map<String, String[]> parameters = request.getParameterMap();
         String relayState = null;
         for(String parameter : parameters.keySet()) {
           if(parameter.equalsIgnoreCase("relaystate")) {
             String[] values = parameters.get(parameter);
             relayState = values[0];
           }
        }
        String reqString = authReq.getSSOurl(relayState);
        response.sendRedirect(reqString);
        resp.setResponse(reqString);
        return resp;
 }
```

http://localhost:8080/ws_em/rest/accounts/consume-saml calls is supposed to take my SAML request and do the authentication . Here I am using the certificate generated in Onelogin SSO Tab

```
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/consume-saml")
    public com.onelogin.saml.Response SAMLAuthenticationResponse(){
        com.onelogin.saml.Response samlResponse = null;
        String certificateS ="c"; //Certificate downloaded from Onelogin SSO Tab
        AccountSettings accountSettings = new AccountSettings();
        accountSettings.setCertificate(certificateS);
        samlResponse = new com.onelogin.saml.Response(accountSettings,request.getParameter("SAMLResponse"),request.getRequestURL().toString());
       if (samlResponse.isValid()) {
           // the signature of the SAML Response is valid. The source is trusted
            java.io.PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.write("OK!");
            String nameId = samlResponse.getNameId();
            writer.write(nameId);
            writer.flush();
      } else {
         // the signature of the SAML Response is not valid
        java.io.PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.write("Failed\n");
        writer.write(samlResponse.getError());
        writer.flush();
      }
            return samlResponse;
}
```

I am getting this error

> Federation Exception: Malformed URL. Please contact your
>   administrator.

It doesn't seem to come inside the ACS url I have inside my app.

Is there any mistakes in my configuration ? Or is there  a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACS is Assertion Consumer Service, is the endpoint that process at the SP the SAMLResponse sent by the Identity Provider, so the http://localhost:8080/ws_em/rest/accounts/consume-saml process and validate the SAMLResponse.

Do you have verbose trace error? Malformed URL must be that the code is trying to build a URL var with a non URL string.

BTW, You are using the java-saml toolkit, but the 1.0 version instead the recommended [2.0](https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml/tree/v2.0.0).

I highly recommend you to use the 2.0 and before work on your integration, try to run the [app example](https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml/tree/v2.0.0/samples)

Comment: Thank you so much,  I have upgraded to V2.0 and everything worked. I was totally confused while using 1.0 , Now its clear thank you :)

Comment: One more doubt I have, code inside each of the jsp files I made as separate rest calls,  but which one should be a get service and which should be post ?

Comment: dologin I am giving as a GET request and acs as POST I am getting this error **SAML Response not found, Only supported HTTP_POST Binding**

Comment: The java-saml toolkits only accepts SAMLResponse on HTTP-POST binding (ACS expects a SAMLResponse parameter inside the POST parameter) , and rest of SAML Messages sent or received, uses the HTTP-Redirect binding.

Comment: Let me reply you on the new Q you created:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40175122/samlresponse-null-in-acs-request-url-using-onelogin-toolkit