# SAMLResponse null in ACS request url :using onelogin toolkit

Tags: java, web-services, saml-2.0, onelogin

I am using [Onelogin 2.0 toolkit](https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml/tree/v2.0.0) . Instead of having Login and ACS as jsp files I have added them as rest services. I am getting this error when my IdP redirects to ACS Service Url.

> SAML Response not found, Only supported HTTP_POST Binding

In request to ACS service SAMLResponse parameter is coming as null. How can I fix this ?

```
@Path("/saml")
public class SAMLAuthService {
    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;

    @Context
    HttpServletResponse response;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/dologin")
    public void SAMLLogin(){
        try {
            Auth auth = new Auth(CommonUtils.samlPropertyFileName,request, response);
            System.out.println("Calling SAML Login::");
            auth.login();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/acs")
    public Response SAMLACS()
            throws ExecException {
        Response samlResponse = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Calling SAML ACS::");
            Auth auth = new Auth(CommonUtils.samlPropertyFileName,request, response);
            auth.processResponse();
            if (!auth.isAuthenticated()) {
                System.out.println("Not Authenticated");
            }

            List<String> errors = auth.getErrors();
            if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
                if (auth.isDebugActive()) {
                    String errorReason = auth.getLastErrorReason();
                    if (errorReason != null && !errorReason.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println(errorReason);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Map<String, List<String>> attributes = auth.getAttributes();
                String nameId = auth.getNameId();
                System.out.println("NameId::"+nameId);
                if (attributes.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("No Attributes");
                }
                else {
                    Collection<String> keys = attributes.keySet();
                    for(String name :keys){
                        List<String> values = attributes.get(name);
                        System.out.println(name+"::");
                        for(String value :values) {
                            System.out.print(value);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return samlResponse;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Auth](https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml/blob/v2.0.0/toolkit/src/main/java/com/onelogin/saml2/Auth.java#L185) constructor that you are using expects a HttpServletRequest request object with a SAMLResponse POST parameter

If you don't have that HttpServletRequest object, you can build it using the [makeHttpRequest](https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml/blob/v2.0.0/toolkit/src/main/java/com/onelogin/saml2/servlet/ServletUtils.java#L24)

You can use the [SAML Tracer](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/) to analyze the SAML flow between the IdP and the SP. You may be sure that the IdP is sending a SAMLResponse. I'm not familiar with the "Rest approach" you are using, but you may see the way to get the SAMLResponse and build the HttpServletRequest object injecting that parameter.

Comment: SAML Tracer says 204 No content Error. I checked the request headers for both the jsp request and rest request. header size and url alone differs

Comment: When you execute the SAML flow.. Do you see the AuthNRequest sent by the java-saml to the IdP?
Why you need to follow the "Rest approach" instead of clone what is working on the examples provided?

Comment: I am not familiar with jsp :| .  AuthNRequest is sent successfully. Anyway now I am doing it with jsp itself.